# getting constraint error while inserting data into same table while using hibernate generator

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm using hibernate as well as the procedure to add values into the same table. After inserting values into a table using procedure by getting the max value of ID and incrementing it by one, then I tried to enter data using hibernate and get constraint error

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "Generator", strategy = "increment", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"), 
            @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1") 
})
@GeneratedValue(generator = "Generator")
```

I like to know why I get constraint error, is there any problem with the specified generator.
Is there any other way to insert row via the procedure(using Oracle database) and hibernate

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: WARN  (SqlExceptionHelper.java:137)     - SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000
 ERROR (SqlExceptionHelper.java:142)     - ORA-00001: unique constraint (ABC.PERSONS_PK) violated